# Create reveal push menu with fixed position sidebar

Tags: jquery, html, css

Trying to create an effect like the one seen here: [Wanda.net/uk](http://www.wanda.net/uk)
I have my sidebar div within the main content area with the trigger outside and i'm using the jqPanels plugin to shift this area. However, with my incredibly novice and fumbling jQuery skills, I am unable to determine how to edit the script in order to get the sidebar to move along with the content area when the trigger activates the push/reveal.

Trigger/Sidebar HTML:

```
<div id="triggerWrap">
    <div id="profile_trigger" class="hide-for-small">
        <div class="reveal"><i class="fi-torso large icon"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="revealp panel">
        <span class="close">Close</span> Reveal menu
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row site main">
    <!--Sidebar -->
    <div id="hedWrap" class="hide-for-small">
        <header id="header">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <h5>Juju Skincare</h5>
                <div class="side-nav">
                    <b></b>
                    <a href="#anchor1" id="scrollTo1">Buy Juju Products</a>
                    <a href="#anchor2" id="scrollTo2">Our Story</a>
                    <a href="#anchor3" id="scrollTo3">Ingredients Glossary</a>
                    <a href="#anchor4" id="scrollTo4">Contact Us</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
    .site {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
}
#triggerWrap {
    width: 42px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 101;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: $sand;
}
#profile_trigger {
    width: 42px;
    height: 100%;
    background: $sand;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 101;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-right: 1px solid $beachwood;
    webkit-transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s ease-in-out;
}
#profile_trigger .reveal {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
//reveal menu styles (2 rules)
.main.ractive {
    margin-left: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.revealp {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#hedWrap {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 42px;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 280px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: $sand;
}
#header {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -200px;
    display: block;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: inherit !important;
    padding: 3rem 3rem 3rem;
}
.side-nav a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .25rem;
    color: #A36A32;
}
.side-nav b {
    height: 1px;
    margin: 21px auto 17px auto;
}
```

jQuery

```
    $(function(){
var o=$('.overlayp'),r=$('.revealp'),p=$('.pushp'),ob=$('.overlay'),rb=$('.reveal'),pb=$('.push'),m=$('.main'),panel=$('.panel');
  panel.css('min-height',m.outerHeight());

ob.click(function(){
  o.toggleClass('active');
});
rb.click(function(){
  m.toggleClass('ractive');
});
  pb.click(function(){
  m.toggleClass('pactive');
  p.toggleClass('active');
});
  $('.close').click(function(){
    o.removeClass('active');
    p.removeClass('active'); m.removeClass('pactive').removeClass('ractive');
  });
});
```

I removed my pathetic code to animate the fixed sidebar — I'm starting from scratch again, so any insight or anything to point me in the right direction at all would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I liked your question, so I did a bit of work. Check out this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvRdbm

It seems to me like it works perfectly. Let me know if the behaviour is different.

Let's walk trough the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="controller inactive">
  <div id="preview" class="column">The reveal preview</div>
  <div id="menu" class="column">The revealed menu</div>
  <div id="content1" class="column">Content 1</div>
  <div id="content2" class="column">Content 2</div>  
</div>
```

This is a very simple structure. The magic happens with the controller - it toggles between active and inactive. content2 is irrelevant and exists only to highlight the similarities to wanda.com

**CSS**

Theres a fair bit of css going on, so I'll only look at the relevant parts, full css is in the pen.

```
.column { float: left; }

#menu { position: absolute; }

#preview {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  transition: left 0.5s ease;
}
.inactive #preview { left: 0; }
.active #preview { left: -10%; }

#content1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s ease;
}
.inactive #content1 { margin-left: 10%; }
.active #content1 { margin-left: 20%; }
```

All colums are floated so they're next to each other. Using display: inline-block should probably work as well.

The actual menu gets an absolute position, so it just stays in the same spot and the other stuff can hang over it. That's also why the other have z-index: 2

preview toggles between an offset of 0 (inactive) and -10% (active). You always need to use negative it's defined width, so it slides just out of view.

content1 toggles between the defined width of the preview (inactive) and the defined width of the menu (active)

**jQuery (no Plugin, would be easy with classic JS)**

```
$('#preview').on('mouseover.revealMenu', function() {
  $('.controller').toggleClass('active inactive');

  $('#menu').on('mouseleave.revealMenu', function() {
    hideMenuTimer = setTimeout(hideMenu, 1000);
  });

  $('#menu').on('mouseenter.revealMenu', function() {
    clearTimeout(hideMenuTimer);
  });

});

function hideMenu() {
  $('#menu').off('mouseleave.revealMenu');
  $('.controller').toggleClass('active inactive');
}
```

First, when we *mouseover* the reveal menu, it instantly toggles between the states, revealing the menu (in a smooth animation, thanks to css-transition!).

Also, when We mouseover, we register two events to the menu: Mouseleave and mouseenter.
When the mouse leaves the menu, we wait for 1 second, then hide it. If it enters the menu again, the timer resets.

In hideMenu(), we also unbind the mouseleave-event again. If we don't do that, it jerks around a lot when quickly opening and closing the menu.

And that's it! No plugin (other than jQuery), very little code. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can use off-canvs menu for this it is bit simple to implement in bootstrap and also in foundation
Thanks